# Need to verify date span condition with query

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 2 spans in my Category table, each one covering half span October. When there is an enrolment done for the complete month of October, it should verify that the complete October month span in enrolment is covered in Cateoryspans.

```
CATEGORY:
beginDT             EndDt
01-sep-2018        16-oct-2018
17-sep-2018        31-Dec-2018

MEMBER Enroll:
BeginDt           EndDt
01-sep-2018      31-oct-2018
```

When I want to consider the MEMBER ENROLL for the month of October. Need a query to verify if complete month of October is being covered in CATEGORY table spans.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be tough to swing with your current table design.  I recommend instead maintaining a calendar table of values which you want to verify appear in the category table.  In this case, consider the following table, inlined:

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT date '2018-10-01' AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-10-02' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-10-03' FROM dual UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT date '2018-10-31' FROM dual
)
```

Then, we can simply left join this calendar table to the category table to flag any dates in October which are not covered:

```
SELECT
    c.dt
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN category cat
    ON c.dt BETWEEN CAT.beginDT AND cat.EndDt
WHERE
    cat.beginDT IS NULL;
```

Depending on the exact output you want, we could rework the above query.  But hopefully it is clear that it is much easier to report what you want with a calendar table.